# Ranked matches in Supreme Commander 2

Tags: supreme-commander-2

Are there still people playing ranked matches in Supreme Commander 2? I never get matched up with anyone, the game just keeps on looking for an opponent..

Could it be a firewall issue or something else?

Comment: Of course it could be a connection issue on your end. Do you use a firewall or does your router block ports or your ISP?

Comment: Hmm, I think you should ask this question at the steam forum about this game. I doubt arqade has much active supreme commander 2 players.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like Steam takes care of all the NAT and firewall stuff, so that seams to be working OK.I found the solution anyways. But you are right, it's probably not the most active community any more. After all, the game is getting old, and was never truly mainstream/big.

Comment: Sucks, good to hear it got resolved. You should now accept your question. If you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like most people are playing without the Infinite War Battlepack Expansion. Found a check box to disable the expansion pack, and suddenly there was a lot more going on :)

Answer (score -2):

Nobody plays ranked matches, people dont want to wait. And the less people play, the more people are forced to stop playing ranked matches.

The ranked matchmaking was a failure, people prefer to play in lobbies, it is way faster and more fun. Nobody is playing ranked so that is why you cant get an opponent ;D

Comment: Is this a valid assumption or are you just trying to seem informed? Besides, the accepted answer above you states the opposite, while in fact people play it without the expansion pack.